# TFS custom widget link unauthorized

Tags: tfs, widget, azure-devops, tfs-2015

I am currently building a custom widget which has links in it. If a link is clicked, the newly opened tab has no authorization. It says `the unauthorized access is forbidden. Client authorization required.`

[image]
I am building the link via javascript.

```
var newLinkButton = (url, text) => $('<a>', {
    class: 'btn btn-default btn-xs',
    href: url,
    role: 'button',
    text: text
});
```

and set the base target in the header to `_blank`

```
<base target="_blank" />
```

The TFS sets access right equal to the ones from the iframe in which it was called. That is anonym. How do I tell TFS to take an already existing authorization?

Comment: Where do you place the link and which tab does it open?

Answer (score 1):

You need to redirect to another page (not open a new page) from current page. Change _blank to _top.

```
<base target="_top" />
```

Comment: `_top` has the same effect as `_parent`. It does not open a new Tab. It just uses the current tab.

Comment: @Greaka Yes, it uses the current tab. I think you can't open a new tab, because you can't add additional header when open a new tab.